# Kondo effect--why magnetization is key

Tags: condensed-matter, many-body

Starting from the Anderson model for an impurity, one can show that in certain cases a magnetized state is preferred. Assuming a singly-occupied state, we can write down the s-d Hamiltonian. Using the diagrammatic approach, it is possible to demonstrate that as the temperature is lowered, the scattering rate goes up, increasing the resistivity of the system.

My question is: why is magnetization necessary for this to occur? From the Scholarpedia article written in part by Jun Kondo (http://www.scholarpedia.org/article/Kondo_effect), we see in Eq.(3) that the magnetization is not explicit at all. The parameter $J$ can be any interaction and the expression looks like a scattering with an intermediate momentum $k''$. What does having a magnetized impurity give that a simple coupling to a localized site does not?